# create snippet for txt scope

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have created sample snippet for txt extension, but it does not working. I cant able to find out the issue.

I am using ST3

I am using the sample.

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
Hello, ${1:this} is a ${2:snippet}.
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>hello</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.txt</scope>
</snippet>
```

I saved the file in

> AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User

saved file as

> hello.sublime-snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the snippet to work in the text-scope, you need to set it to `text` not `source.txt`.

Also, I *think* snippets and completions don't work in the text-scope by default. In that case you have to add the scope to `auto_complete_selector` in your user settings.

Comment: If you just want the snippet to work in plain text files, the scope needs to be `text.plain`, as `text` will also trigger the snippet in HTML, Markdown, and other syntaxes. Also, you don't need to alter `auto_complete_selector`.