# How to use snippets for all scopes?

Tags: sublimetext3

If I change the document type from "Plain Text" to other scope it works, but there is no scope limit for the snippet.

I tried "[Sublime Text 3 snippet not working in plain text file with no extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34793613/sublime-text-3-snippet-not-working-in-plain-text-file-with-no-extension/34793713#34793713)" but had no luck.

In syntax-specific ("plain text") user settings I added this:

```
"extensions":
[
    "txt", ""
],
```

Comment: Are you saying you have a snippet that doesn't have a `<scope>` tag in it but it still doesn't work in plain text files?

Comment: what have you done so far? Please share an minimal (non) functional example to illustrate the issue. In which scope do you want to use the snippet?

Comment: @jack.sparrow All scope

Comment: You don't need to set extensions. set `auto_complete_selector` with no scope. I recreated the configuration on a pristine install and it is working for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create snippet for txt scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27675067/create-snippet-for-txt-scope)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a snippet without specifying any scope it will be active for every file type:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
Hello, ${1:this} is a Sublime Text ${2:snippet} for all scopes.
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>hello_all_scopes</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

To make the snippet visible as a popup on auto completion add the scope to the user preferences:

```
{
    "auto_complete_selector": "text"
}
```

Note that the key `auto_complete_selector` has a default setting that is overridden by the user key. You'll most likely want to add the default settings in your custom configuration. Scope selection can be further refined or other scopes added to the list, according to your requirements.

Comment: The `auto_complete_selector` doesn't control when snippets are available, it only controls when the auto completion popup will automatically appear. In a completely stock portable install of Sublime, the snippet generated by `Tools > Developer > New Snippet` will appear as a snippet in the command palette in any file (even text) and will also automatically trigger if you add a trigger for it and type it followed by pressing `Tab`,regardless of the setting of `auto_complete_selector`.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I am so used to auto completion that I couldn't see it working even though it did. Thanks for the correction, I edited the answer.

Comment: I set `auto_complete_selector` with no scope to work for all scope.